# Adding \n to the end of each line

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Hello I have this very simple app. In my main window, there is a NSTextView and I am able to get text from it. It is meant so that text pasted in it will be 1 sentence each line. There is also a button and by the click of the button, the text that was pasted in the NSTextView will add a "\n" to the end of each line. How do I do that?

EX.
Pasted
Hello Stackoverflow.
I am having a good day.

After formatted
Hello Stackoverflow.\n
I am having a good day.\n

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace each occurrance of a period in your input text `'.'` with a period followed by a newline `'.\n'`:

```
NSString *str = @"Hello Stackoverflow. I am having a good day.";

str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"."
                                     withString:@".\n"];
```

This is a very simplistic example which assumes all your lines end with a period and there are no periods anywhere inside a line of text

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you just need to substitute every `.` character with `.\n` although there will be exceptions, for example if an IP address or floating-point number is entered, it would be messed up.

But in the general case:

```
NSString *transformed = [input stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"."
                                                         withString:@".\n"];
```

Comment: what if I would like to just add "\n" to the end of each line?

Comment: @user1927992 Sorry, I don't understand.  If the user enters a newline into the textfield it will be preserved already.

Comment: Is there another way to do this because I am afarid that the user might not always end with a 'period' or a 'question mark' or a 'exlacamation mark'. All I know is that I need '\n' at the end of each line. Is there any way to do this?